# rmi example compute.task

Tags: java, oracle, rmi

I'm new to RMI/JAVA and was using the rmi tutorial on Oracle's site
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/client.html

I was able to follow the entire thing until it came to the Client.pi class.
In the first line is code for importing the Task interface
import compute.Task

My question is,how does Java know where to get the task interface from?It is a non-remote interface on the server and so I'm a little confused as to how it will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

you would provide the Task interface along with the remote interface (Compute) as part of a client API jar.

typically, when designing any sort of RMI server system, you will end up with 2 modules, the server API and the server implementation (which will depend on the API).  you would then provide the server API jar to anyone who is building an RMI client for your server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I'll have to implement the system to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

The `Task` interface is common to both the client and server code, so there needs to be copies in both the client and server.

The `Pi` implementation of `Task` needs to be available to the client. Ideally the server shouldn't know about the client's tasks, so shouldn't have its own copy. So RMI on the client annotates the class in the object stream with a URL where the code can be loaded. The server uses this annotation to dynamically load the implementation class, which may have been written after the server instance was started.

Whilst this is a neat party trick, loading remote code can be tricky to do safely. Setting the `java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly` to `true` disables the feature, which I strongly recommend.

Comment: Wouldn't disabling remote code defeat an important purpose of RMI viz. running client tasks on a powerful server.

Comment: @user1630812 It's only a Hello World example. In real-life the situation is typically more static.